# A measure of the surface area of the intersection of a sphere with a cone

Tags: measure-theory, area

I will be as detailed as possible on the problem.

Think of the following. Take the unit hypersphere $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^p: \Vert x\Vert_2=1\}$. I have a matrix $M$ of size $n\times p$ with $n\leq p$ so that $M\cdot x \geq 0$ produces a linear system of inequalities. I am trying to calculate some measure $\mu$ for the surface area of the intersection of the hypersphere with radius one with a linear set of inequalities, that is the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^p: M\cdot x \geq 0 \text{ and }  x\in S\}$.

To further exemplify what I am talking about think of it in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I have a system of three inequalities given by $x + y + z > 0$, $-x + 2 y - z < 0$, $x + y - z > 0$ pictured below:

[image]

Now I get the set $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1, x + y + z > 0, -x + 2 y - z < 0, x + y - z > 0\}$ which is pictured below:

[image]

How can I measure the surface area of the boundary of the cone generated? I do not want the volume of the sphere, but definitely the surface area would work. I am not only interested in the particular solution of this problem. What I want is to implement a code that uses this structure and calculates the surface area.

Comment: Can you please tell how you generated the figures in the question ? Using Mathematica or MATLAB or ... ? Maybe we could use the software to calculate the surface area of the resulting object using built in functions ?

Comment: Mathematica.Simple `ContourPlot` and this `RegionPlot3D[
 And @@ {x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, x + y + z > 0, -x + 2 y - z < 0, 
   x + y - z > 0}, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, {z, -1.2, 1.2}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 10, PlotStyle -> None]` for the last one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like we might need to use algebraic geometry which I haven't studied. So, I will try a more naive approach to this one. I'm going to solve this first for a very simple case and based on the suggestions and feedback I get, I will try to generalize the answer. 
 
Simple Case : 
$ p=2, n=1 $
Step 1 : Let's say we have the following inequality : $x_1 + x_2 > 0$ and the equation for circle $x_1^2+x_2^2 =1$
Step 2 : To find out the points where the line intersects the circle we need to solve the following system :
$x_1 + x_2 = 0$
$x_1^2+x_2^2 =1$
We get two solutions : $(1/\sqrt2),-1/\sqrt2),(-1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2)$.
Step 3 : 
$t_1 =$ angle made by $(1/\sqrt2,-1/\sqrt2)$ with positive $x$ axis.
$t_2=$ angle made by $(-1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2)$ with positive $x$ axis.
Step 4 : Depending on the sign of the inequality, 
 required length =$ (t_2 - t_1) + $ distance between $(1/\sqrt2,-1/\sqrt2)$ and $(-1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2)$.
 or 
 required length =$ 2\pi-(t_2 - t_1) + $ distance between $(1/\sqrt2,-1/\sqrt2)$ and $(-1/\sqrt2,1/\sqrt2)$.

This is only the simplest case. I don't know how it can be extended when we have two lines i.e., $n=2$. 
In step 2, we needed to solve non-linear system of equations for which I feel there must be standard algorithms. 
In step 3, we needed find out angle made by a vector with positive x-axis for which I feel there must be standard algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

No integration is required. Simply, find the vertices of the spherical triangle (intersections plane-plane-sphere) an use spherical trigonometry.